# How do I fix - could not stat path - no such file or directory when publishing gatsby site to github-pages?

Tags: github, github-pages, gatsby

I have a Gatsby site I need to publish to Github-Pages.

- Gatsby Develop - works OK
- Gatsby Build -- works OK (no issues found)

Then I execute: `gh-pages -b master -d public --dest docs`

It immediately returns this error every time:

> warning: Could not stat path 'docs/action_complete-0b5e239fbe8025f0bfb3a38b6c69e923.': No such file or directory

Despite it being a "warning" it stops execution at that point.

Multiple days of Googling has not helped in finding a workable solution.

I've tried deleting the offending files (not a simple task I will say!). But if I delete one, there are several others that generate the same error.
Despite the error saying no such file or directory, the files do exist in Public.

I can manually publish other files to Github-Pages successfully.  Any attempt to manually publish a file without an extension fails with stat path error. If you attempt to open one of the offending files, they are binary and unreadable.

Attempting to copy or delete the files generates a stat error. Have to jump through hoops to delete them.

I have no idea where in the code that might be causing this error.

I expected the files to be copied from public to docs folder and then pushed to the Github-Pages configured location.

Comment: Hi Sean, have you tried running `NODE_DEBUG=gh-pages gh-pages -b master -d public --dest docs` to see if there's any additional info about the error?

Comment: Perhaps watch a quick introductory video to `Process Monitor`- it records HDD, Registry, Process and Network activity in real-time. Run ProcMon quickly while you reproduce the problem, then filter to Hdd only and work out where it is looking for the *Could not stat path 'docs/action_complete-0b5e239fbe8025f0bfb3a38b6c69e923.': No such file or directory*

Comment: Thank you.  I will try those ideas and see what happens.